# How to print all rows in one page with Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports 2011. I am totally new to crystal reports and reporting tools in general. I just added my data fields to the details section, but instead of showing all the rows in one page, a new page is created for each row. I did not use any grouping or change the section paging settings.

This only happens for a blank report, when using the report wizard it works fine, but I can't see the difference between what I did and what the report wizard did.

Comment: What language are you writing on your crystal report?

Comment: I am using Crystal Reports 2011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to have been a mix up with the sections, I've understood how these work now and got it to work. Thanks for the help.

I had 2 details section, so for every row in details1 it also displayed the information of details2 (which I only wanted to appear once). So I moved the data of details2 into a report footer.

Comment: can you explain what is the issue it might also help me... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your report and then go to Section Expert check Is Keep togather is checked
or New Page after or before in not checked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that "New Page After" and "New Page Before" are not ticked. Also, Adjust the section sizes to the minimum you need.
In general, it sounds like you have a row data, inserted into the page header/footer section instead of the details section and therefore presented in each page...